# Close lightbox on click outside of the child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a lightbox without using a jquery plugin, and now I'm trying to close it by clicking on the `close` button or by clicking anywhere else outside of the white area (`.white_content`) 
**[Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uvxzwdba/)**

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display='inline';">
    Show lightbox
</button>

<!-- LIGHTBOX CODE BEGIN -->
<div id="lightbox" class="lightbox" style="display:none">
    <div class="white_content">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display='none';" class="textright">Close</a>
            <p>Click anywhere to close the lightbox.</p>
            <p>Use Javascript to insert anything here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- LIGHTBOX CODE END -->
```

Although it's not just like I want it. I want it to close only if I click on the dark area of the lightbox and not on the white container (`.white_content`), I've heard that event.propagation can be a bad thing to use, so here's how I'm closing the lightbox

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('button').length) {
    $(".lightbox").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can change you condition bit like below

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).has('.white_content').length) {
        $(".lightbox").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: brilliant, it targets the child element with class .white_content and excludes the click action for it, perfect, simple, excellent.

Answer (score 2):

Most lightbox scripts are using two div-s, content and overlay. Overlay is there for background and to prevent users to click on page content, and also click on overlay can be used to close lightbox.

HTML:

```
<div id="lightbox"> LIGHTBOX CONTENT </div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

JS:

```
$( '#overlay, #close').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#lightbox, #overlay").hide();
});

$( '#show').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#lightbox, #overlay").show();
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fv9mtvsx/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to close the lightbox on any click that isn't targeting the lightbox or one of its children. Your existing code is pretty close:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) { 
    if (!$(event.target).closest('button').length &&
        !$(event.target).closest('.white_content').length) {
        $(".lightbox").hide();
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', function(event) { 
    if (!$(event.target).closest('button').length &&
        !$(event.target).closest('.white_content').length) {
     $(".lightbox").hide();
    }
});
```

```css
.textright {
    float: right;
}
.lightbox {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.white_content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display='inline';">
    Show lightbox
</button>

<!-- LIGHTBOX CODE BEGIN -->
<div id="lightbox" class="lightbox" style="display:none">
    <div class="white_content">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display='none';" class="textright">Close</a>
            <p>Click anywhere to close the lightbox.</p>
            <p>Use Javascript to insert anything here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- LIGHTBOX CODE END -->
```

I'd also recommend using a class to denote whether the lightbox is visible or not, rather than changing the display property directly; that way it's more clear when you check it. Compare `$el.is('.active')` with `$(el).css('display') == 'inline'`